# only last row is been inserted in the database while using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

### AccountTable.java

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class AccountTable { 
    
    private int id;
    private Date txDate;
    private String txType;
    private int accountId;
    private int amount;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getTxDate() {
        return txDate;
    }

    public void setTxDate(Date txDate) {
        this.txDate = txDate;
    }

    public String getTxType() {
        return txType;
    }

    public void setTxType(String txType) {
        this.txType = txType;
    }

    public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

### ReadExcel.java

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ReadExcel {
    static List<AccountTable>acctList = new ArrayList<AccountTable>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<AccountTable>acctdetail=readExcel("D:\\Book1.xlsx");
        excelToDb(acctdetail);
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static List<AccountTable> readExcel(String filepath) {
       try {
           FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new      
       File("D:\\Book1.xlsx"));
   
           XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    
           XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    
           Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
           AccountTable account = new AccountTable();
    
           while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
               Row row = rowIterator.next();
    
               if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                   continue;
               }
    
               Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
               while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                   Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                   if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0 ) {
                    account.setId((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());
                       acctList.add(account);
                       System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   }
                   else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 1 ) {
                       account.setTxDate((Date)cell.getDateCellValue());
                       acctList.add(account);
                       System.out.print(cell.getDateCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   }
                   else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 2 ) {
                       account.setTxType(cell.getStringCellValue());
                       acctList.add(account);
                       System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   }
                   else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 3 ) {
                       account.setAccountId((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                       acctList.add(account);
                       System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   }
                   else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 4 ) {
                       account.setAmount((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                       acctList.add(account);
                       System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   }
               }
              
               System.out.println("");
             }
    
           file.close(); 
           
    }catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
       fnfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
       return acctList;
    }
    
    private static void excelToDb(List<AccountTable> accountDt) {
    
           Configuration c = new Configuration();
           c.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
          
           SessionFactory sf = c.buildSessionFactory();
           
           Session s = sf.openSession();
    
         Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
           
           try {
               for (int i = 0; i < accountDt.size(); i++) {
                  AccountTable acc = accountDt.get(i);
                   s.save(acc);
           }
           
           tx.commit();
           s.close();
    
       } catch (Exception e) {
           tx.rollback();
       }
   }
}
```

### mapping.hbm.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.example.AccountTable" table="account_detail">
     <id name="id" type="int" column="Tx_id">
        </id>
        <property name="txDate" column="Tx_Date" type="date" />
        <property name="txType" column="Account_type" type="string" />
        <property name="accountId" column="Account_id" type="int" />    
        <property name="amount" column="Amount" type="int" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### hibernate.cgf.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">*****</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
       
            <mapping resource="mapping.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I was working on a Java project using Hibernate. I have an Excel file that contains 10 rows. I've successfully retrieved data from Excel file. Now, I have to insert those data to the database.

The problem is only the last row is being added to the table. Other rows are not being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line `AccountTable account = new AccountTable();`
inside While loop.